# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a bit lost. I an getting the Rails 4 error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError.  I understand that this means I need to permit items to pass, which I have done, but I must be missing something.

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
       redirect_to @post
    end

    private
        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :comment, :body)
        end

end
```

Create Comments Migration

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :post
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :comments
  end  
end
```

What am I missing here?  Let me know if you need to see any other code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of

```
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
```

you want

```
@comment = @post.comments.create!(comment_params)
```

You did all the hard work without using the permitted attributes!

Comment: Blah! I knew this had to be trivial. Thanks!